# Pull file from Android sdcard using gradle task

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to run a task in gradle which will pull a file placed on Android device sdcard.
Below is the code I am trying.

```
File copyFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/abc.png")
project.logger.warn("copy file path:"+copyFile.getAbsolutePath())
if (copyFile.exists()) {
      project.logger.warn("file exist:yes")
 }else{
      project.logger.warn("file exist:no")
}
```

The problem is the file exists on sdcard, still I get the message in `else` part "file exist:no".
Can anyone help me to get the file on sdcard?

Comment: Does gradle run on the device ?!? If not you probably need ADB to copy the file

Answer (score 1):

Gradle runs on your development machine. It not running on your Android device. Your development machine does not have a `/storage/emulated/0/abc.png` file.

You are welcome to try to have Gradle run an **`adb pull`** command to pull the file from the device to your development machine. [This Gradle plugin](https://github.com/novoda/gradle-android-command-plugin) may make this task easier, though I have not tried it.